# portlet-liferay.xml: How to use portal-javascript-header correctly

Tags: liferay

I copied jquery.js to `WebContent/js/jquery/jquery.js`. Now I want to use that file in certain portlets. To do this I created a liferay-portlet.xml that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC
    "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.0.0//EN"
    "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_0_0.dtd">

<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>MyPortletName</portlet-name>
        <header-portal-javascript>/js/jquery/jquery.js</header-portal-javascript>
    </portlet>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

If I access the portlet Liferay generates this line:

```html
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery.js?browserId=firefox&amp;minifierType=js&amp;languageId=en_US&amp;b=6100&amp;t=1326630657000" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That leads to a `WARN  [404_jsp:?] /js/jquery/jquery.js` in the logging console.

Is it really correct that the URL looks like this? If I had two war-files, both containing a js-file with the same path, how would Liferay distinguish those two?

What do I need to do to get my setup working?

Using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE (Paton / Build 6100 / December 15, 2011)

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: @Jonny: The version I am using hides in the last line of my question ;-)

Comment: Doh!! :) It's Monday morning!

Comment: @yankee, how did you create this portlet and how are you deploying it? Are you using the [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide)?

Comment: @RP: Yes, I am using Liferay IDE. I created the portlet by creating a Spring-controller-class that handles stuff and adding a couple of lines to my portlet.xml file ;-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```xml
<header-portlet-javascript>/js/jquery/jquery.js</header-portlet-javascript>
```

isntead of

```xml
<header-portal-javascript>/js/jquery/jquery.js</header-portal-javascript>
```

if you put js-files in to portlet

Because regarding comments in DTD, header-portal-javascript sets the path of JavaScript relative to the portal's context path. And header-portlet-javascript sets the path of JavaScript relative to the portlet's context path.

Answer (score 1):

The location for jQuery looks incorrect.

If you're bundling this with your own plugin named foobar-portlet the correct path would be (provided that you use the same liferay-portlet.xml):

`foobar-portlet/docroot/js/jquery/jquery.js`

Comment: Would that be the path where the file should be within my eclipse-project, the URL to access the file or the string I should insert in liferay-portlet.xml? My project actually has a number of portlets, several of them using jquery.

Comment: If you're in the liferay-portlet.xml then the path will be /js/jquery/jquery.js. However if you're in another portlet, then the above path is what you will need (minus the /docroot/ part). However this then creates a dependency on that portlet being deployed in order for jQuery to work.

Comment: @yankee, I am assuming that you're using the Liferay SDK and that the portlet you're building created by the SDK. Assuming those things, in your foobar-portlet project folder there should a docroot folder.

Comment: @RP: Actually I started developing on WebSphere Portal using Rational Application Developer (avoiding WebSphere-specific features keeping to JSR-268 as far as possible). Then I imported the project into Liferay IDE continuing development there. Always worked fine without a folder called docroot so far.

Comment: I see, actually, the docroot folder is for the Liferay SDK. Once deployed the content docroot is copied into a WAR so the docroot folder goes away. Unfortunately, I'm not to familiar with WebSphere but your settings look correct as long as you have the jQuery file in `/js/jquery/jquery.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

**jQuery is bundled with Liferay 5**, check the version of Liferay and which jQuery version it has bundled and see if this meets your needs. However I believe it's not in Liferay 6 or 6.1, but I could be wrong about that.

And:

If you want to have a JavaScript library available to all of your portlets you're better off adding it to the theme(s) that you use rather than the portlets. This way it will be globally accessible. The downside is that if you're distributing your portlet then you should make people aware of this dependency.

Otherwise if you just want it available to a small group of your portlets, then follow what RP said.

Here's some good reference on [using jQuery with Liferay 6](http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/5241428).

Comment: The only difference in the link you supplied to my project that I spotted is that the folder that is called "WebContent" in my project is called "docroot" over there. I tried renaming my WebContent folder to "docroot", but that did not change anything at all.

Comment: Your liferay-portlet.xml path is correct (if that's the portlet you're trying to reference jQuery). But your HTML code is incorrect, and should be /foobar-portlet/js/jquery/jquery.js, but as I said that will create a dependency on that portlet being deployed to use jQuery. Have you considered adding jQuery to your Theme?

Comment: In the example above I want to use jQuery exclusively from "MyPortletName". The HTML code is automatically generated by Liferay, I opened a page with my portlet, I clicked "show source" in my browser and copied the tag from there. How can that be?

Comment: I think SquAreRoot may have actually answered your question below. You may want to use header-PORTLET-javascript instead of header-PORTAL-javascript. However if you want jQuery to be accessible by all portlets then add it to a theme.